# pygame keeps crashing after it runs for a while

Tags: python, crash, pygame

This program somehow keeps crashing after running for a few seconds. Can someone help me?
It's a program for visualising sorting algorithms. I'm sorry if I'm doing a lot of things wrong but i just started using pygame and I'm still not completely sure how everything works.
Thanks for your help!

```
import random
import time
import pygame

pygame.init()

display_width=1200
display_height=800

gamedisplay=pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
clock=pygame.time.Clock()

correct=[]
shuffled=[]
for i in range(100):
    correct.append(i+1)
    shuffled.append(i+1)
random.shuffle(shuffled)

block_width=display_width/(len(shuffled))

def bar(block_width,shuffled):
    for i in shuffled:
        colour=(i,i,255)
        pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, colour, 
[shuffled.index(i)+shuffled.index(i)*block_width,750,block_width,-i-i*2.5])

def inserting(shuffled):
    a=0
    for i in range(len(shuffled)):
        x=a
        while shuffled[x]>shuffled[x+1] or x+1==len(shuffled):
            change=shuffled[x]
            shuffled.remove(shuffled[x])
            shuffled.insert(x+1,change)
        if a+1!=len(shuffled)-1:
            a=a+1
        else:
            a=0
    return shuffled

def Loop(block_width,shuffled,correct):
    FPS=10
    while shuffled!=correct:
        shuffled=inserting(shuffled)
        bar(block_width,shuffled)
        pygame.display.update()
        time.sleep(1/FPS)
    bar(block_width,shuffled)
    pygame.display.update()
    print(shuffled)

Loop(block_width,shuffled,correct)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to use an event loop (`for event in pygame.event.get():`) or call [`pygame.event.pump()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) each frame, otherwise the operating system thinks the program has locked up. I recommend to restructure the `Loop` function in this way:

```
def Loop(block_width,shuffled,correct):
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # A clock to limit the frame rate.
    FPS=10
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # Quit if the user closes the window.
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        # Fill the background with a color each frame.
        gamedisplay.fill((30, 30, 30))
        # If not sorted, keep sorting.
        if shuffled != correct:
            shuffled = inserting(shuffled)
            bar(block_width,shuffled)
            pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(FPS)

Loop(block_width,shuffled,correct)
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) recommends to use snake_case names (lower case with underscores) for variables and functions, e.g. `def loop():`. Upper camelcase is for classes.

Comment: just one question,, what's sys?

Comment: You actually don't need `sys.exit()` here (I've removed it), since the game will quit normally as any other program when the function returns and the program reaches the end of the file. The `pygame.quit()` call is only needed if you use the IDLE IDE, because it can't close the window.